# WXS - How to modify installation directory to append extra folder to install directory in Wxs file

Tags: wix, wix-extension

How to modify installation directory to append extra folder to install directory in Wxs file. 
I am new to wxs file creation. Suppose my installation directory is **C:\Sample\Test** then I want to append one more directory path (example: **C:\Sample\Testz\data\install** ) to this location when we click on Next button on selecting installation directory. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another property to fix it.

e.g.

```
<Property Id="AnotherDir" value="[FirstDir]\data\install" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. this <Property Id="AnotherDir" value="[FirstDir]\data\install" /> will work for default cases. In case user changes the path in install directrory path by selecting browse dialog, in this case how to change it? Example user selects directory as C:\Example\ then I want ot append extra directories \data\install i.e. C:\Sample\Testz\data\install\ how to acive this?

Comment: You can set the AnotherDir value after the next button clicked.

 e.g.

    `<Publish Dialog="WebDialg" Control="Next" Property="AnotherProperty" value="[FirstDir]\data\install order="1">1</Publish>`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. it is working fine and final installation happening on "C:\Sample\Testz\data\install\". But after the installation (user selected installation location as "C:\Sample\Testz\" and after that dynamically appended directories to it as data\install\) my installation path is pointing to initial selected path i.e. C:\Sample\Testz\. Not to the full installation location. C:\Sample\Testz\data\install\ .